# Erro no Insert: There are more columns in the insert statement than values specified in the values clause

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Quando vou dar um insert buscando dados a partir de outra tabela, esse erro é retornado, o que pode estar de errado com a query ?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CRMRAT (IDCRMRAT, CODCOLIGADA, STATUS, TIPO, IDCRMCLIENTE, IDCRMCOLABORADOR, IDCRMPROJETO, DATA, HORAINICIO, HORAFIM, INTERVALO, KMDESLOCAMENTO, VALORPEDAGIO, VALORALIMENTACAO, VALORHOTEL, VALORESTACIONAMENTO, OUTRASDESPESAS, OBSERVACAO, USUARIOCRIACAO, DATACRIACAO, USUARIOALTERACAO, DATAALTERACAO, IDCRMFATURA, DATAFATURAMENTO)
    VALUES ((SELECT MAX(IDCRMRAT) + 1 AS IDCRMRAT FROM CRMRAT ) , (SELECT CODCOLIGADA, STATUS, TIPO, IDCRMCLIENTE, IDCRMCOLABORADOR, IDCRMPROJETO, DATA, HORAINICIO, HORAFIM, INTERVALO, KMDESLOCAMENTO, VALORPEDAGIO, VALORALIMENTACAO, VALORHOTEL, VALORESTACIONAMENTO, OUTRASDESPESAS, OBSERVACAO, USUARIOCRIACAO, DATACRIACAO, USUARIOALTERACAO, DATAALTERACAO, IDCRMFATURA, DATAFATURAMENTO
            FROM dbo.CRMRAT2 WHERE IDCRMRAT = 11 ))
```

Erro apresentado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como o erro já diz (em tradução livre):

> Erro no `INSERT`: Existem mais colunas na instrução `INSERT` do que valores especificados na cláusula `VALUES`

Nos campos do seu `INSERT` você informa 24 campos mas nos `VALUES` você tem dois `SELECT`. Isso causa o segundo erro mostrado na imagem:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with `EXISTS`

Em tradução livre:

> Somente uma expressão pode ser especificada na lista de seleção quando a subconsulta não é introduzida com `EXISTS`

Para ter o resultado esperado da `query` acima você deve obter, antes de inserir, o maior código da tabela. Após isso, utilize o `ROW_NUMBER` para conseguir um novo código:

```
DECLARE @inicial INT;

SET @inicial = ISNULL((SELECT MAX(IDCRMRAT) + 1 AS IDCRMRAT FROM CRMRAT), 0);

INSERT INTO dbo.CRMRAT(IDCRMRAT,
                       CODCOLIGADA,
                       STATUS,
                       TIPO,
                       IDCRMCLIENTE,
                       IDCRMCOLABORADOR,
                       IDCRMPROJETO,
                       DATA,
                       HORAINICIO,
                       HORAFIM,
                       INTERVALO,
                       KMDESLOCAMENTO,
                       VALORPEDAGIO,
                       VALORALIMENTACAO,
                       VALORHOTEL,
                       VALORESTACIONAMENTO,
                       OUTRASDESPESAS,
                       OBSERVACAO,
                       USUARIOCRIACAO,
                       DATACRIACAO,
                       USUARIOALTERACAO,
                       DATAALTERACAO,
                       IDCRMFATURA,
                       DATAFATURAMENTO)
SELECT @inicial + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CODCOLIGADA),
       CODCOLIGADA,
       STATUS,
       TIPO,
       IDCRMCLIENTE,
       IDCRMCOLABORADOR,
       IDCRMPROJETO,
       DATA,
       HORAINICIO,
       HORAFIM,
       INTERVALO,
       KMDESLOCAMENTO,
       VALORPEDAGIO,
       VALORALIMENTACAO,
       VALORHOTEL,
       VALORESTACIONAMENTO,
       OUTRASDESPESAS,
       OBSERVACAO,
       USUARIOCRIACAO,
       DATACRIACAO,
       USUARIOALTERACAO,
       DATAALTERACAO,
       IDCRMFATURA,
       DATAFATURAMENTO,
  FROM dbo.CRMRAT2
 WHERE IDCRMRAT = 11;
```

---

> [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Numera a saída de um conjunto de resultados. Mais especificamente, retorna o número sequencial de uma linha em uma partição de um conjunto de resultados, começando em 1 na primeira linha de cada partição.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é exatamente o que o erro descreve, você está tentando inserir 6 valores (IDCRMRAT, CODCOLIGADA, STATUS, TIPO, IDCRMCLIENTE e IDCRMCOLABORADOR) mas na parte dos valores apenas selecionou 3 valores (max(IDCRMRAT) + 1), CODCOLIGADA e Status.

Você precisa dizer os outros valores, por ordem, para conseguir inserir os valores.